# "--PHP-alt-" appearing in email body with php 8.1

Tags: php, email, php-8.1

I have upgraded to php 8.1 and now email sent with mail() is arriving with the following at the beginning of the body, where before it didn't:

```
--PHP-alt-4de4a7c8434ad5b8f6adb6e50c35b0da
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

The only difference I see in the header info is that each header line now has a space before it (lines 2-5 below):

```
X-PHP-Script: www.example.com/file.php for 0.0.0.0
 From: Name <name@example.com>
 Reply-To: name@example.com
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-4de4a7c8434ad5b8f6adb6e50c35b0da"
 MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <E1oJ4gz-006Rkx-8b@whub53.webhostinghub.com>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

NOTE: I am using "--PHP-alt-RandomHash" in the body as a method to send an HTML message with a plain text fallback. It is a demonstrated method found in various places.

My code:

```
$headers[] = $from;
$headers[] = "Reply-To: " . $fromemail;
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-" . $random_hash . "\"";
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";

// plain text version
$body[] = "--PHP-alt-$random_hash";
$body[] = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"";
$body[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$body[] = "";
$body[] ="$message";

// html version
$body[] = "--PHP-alt-$random_hash";
$body[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";
$body[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$body[] = "";
$body[] = "<html><head>";
$body[] = "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />";
$body[] = "<title>$subject</title>";
$body[] = "</head>";  
$body[] = "<body>";
$body[] = $message;
$body[] = "</body></html>";
$body[] = "--PHP-alt-$random_hash--";

$success = mail($email, $subject, implode("\r\n", $body), implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: are you sure it wasn't due to `$body[] = "--PHP-alt-$random_hash";"`?

Comment: ? Have I missed the point but `$body[] = "--PHP-alt-$random_hash";`  and `$body[] = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"";` etc You ask why these appear in the body of the email??

Comment: Try what the manual has to say regarding the additional_headers parameter - _"If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822."_ Or pass an array to begin with, you don't have to concatenate the headers into one single string value yourself.

Comment: @BagusTesa & @ProfessorAbronsius - I am not sure where I developed the code that put the code `--PHP-alt-` at the top of the body. I do know it has been working fine until php 8.1. I suppose I will investigate removing that part of the code - or at the very least, trying to find the original examples on the web that show this method of generating emails. Thanks for the reflection.

Comment: This link shows the method of using "--PHP-alt-" to be able to send a message in HTML with a text fallback: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/php-sending-html-email-from-php/

Comment: i do aware the `--PHP-alt-` is used as marker for alternative mail view. but thing is, if its broken, we have to narrow down which message broke it. does it appear after the plain text or before? then we can fiddle around the newline marker (those `\r\n`) to see if any of them broke the mail somehow. apart from php version, finicky mail transfer agents can also be the cause. truth to be told, this is why reusing existing well-maintained library (e.g. `PHPMailer`) can save time.

Comment: You need to put your "boundarie" PHP-alt in the same line of your Content-Type, with an space beetween the two element.

Comment: @Inazo - Thanks for the comment. Looks like the change from 7.4 to 8.1 is that PHP_EOL no longer works as a delimiter for lines - it has to be "\r\n". I thought I had changed them all, but I found one more. Test code works now - I'll see tonight when the live cron code which sends me an email runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in behavior between php v8.1 and v7.4 was that using PHP_EOL caused the `--PHP-alt-` marker for alternative mail view to not be recognized.

Changing it to "\r\n" fixed the issue. I thought I had gotten all of them initially, but there was one more instance of a PHP_EOL in the calling fn.